# Omnipay driver see raw request for debugging

Tags: php, guzzle, omnipay

I am building a custom driver for `Omnipay`.

I am looking for a way to see the raw request from my `HTTP` calls. I would like to see the headers and the body of the request to make sure the output is right and I have not made a mistake.

Some requests in my driver are working so I know the setup is about right, but I am stuck on a specific request. Is there a way to debug?

My code is this, and I extend `Omnipay\Common\Message\AbstractRequest` I am 100% sure that the input variables are correct, but still, the gateway refuses my request.

```
$this->httpClient->request(GET', $url, $headers, $body);
```

I have read that there is a debug-mode for Guzzle, but I don't understand how to pass this option to Guzzle from my Omnipay Request-class.

Thanks in advance!